# Error submitting transaction (NoUnsignedValidator)

Tags: substrate-node-template, election

I'm debugging a substrate based blockchain. I found that at each election this are logged:

```
...  WARN ThreadId(17) txpool: (offchain call) Error submitting a transaction t
o the pool: Pool(UnknownTransaction(UnknownTransaction::NoUnsignedValidator))    
2
... ERROR ThreadId(17) staking:  Error in election offchain worker: OffchainE
lectionError::PoolSubmissionFailed
```

Seems that something is missing but I can not find where should I look for the problem. If it is related to a misconfiguration or custom code is submitting invalid transaction.

If anyone saw this error before any hint will be helpful.

Thanks very much
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the ocw doc's unsigned transaction part: https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/ocw/transactions/

Because there's no code revealed, so I can just guess you don't implement ValidateUnsigned trait for your Pallet.

The trait and implementation are all in the above doc, try it.

Comment: The source code is taken from substrate v3.0.0 tag (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/v3.0.0/frame/staking/src/offchain_election.rs). One followup, which Pallet should implement ValidateUnsigned? the same staking pallet or the transaction is processed in other place?
I understand that the offline worker is invoked Ok, but it generated a transaccion and submits it: 
SubmitTransaction::<T, Call<T>>::submit_unsigned_transaction(call)
  .map_err(|_| OffchainElectionError::PoolSubmissionFailed)
but I could not follow where the tx is submitted (who receives it).
Thanks very much!

Comment: For Question1:
After checking the usage of validate_unsigned, it's mainly used by Applyable which is used to enact a piece of extrinsic information by marshalling and dispatching to a named function call. `So I believe the ValidatedUnsiged trait should be implemented in the pallet which will process that transaction.`

Comment: For Question 2: submit_unsigned_transaction, track the call stack, you'll get  sp_runtime::offchain::TransactionPool submit_transaction which will `Submit transaction.The transaction will end up in the pool and be propagated to others.`. The doc link is here: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/offchain/trait.TransactionPool.html